# Autoenter a partir del caracter especificado

Tags: c#

Buenas gente y feliz año nuevo 2.022 a todos y a todas:

En modo consola con C#, al escribir un texto cuando lo pide en

```html
string variable = Console.read();
```

Quiero que por ejemplo, que por cada texto que escribo, automáticamente si llega al caracter 25, que haga autoreturn. Escribes, cuando pulsas Enter en un archivo de texto plano de Windows, salta al renglón siguiente pero este en modo consola lo hace automáticamente.

¿Alguna idea?

Un cordial saludos y a pasarlo bien. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira a ver si algo así, es lo que buscas :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "";
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    do
    {
        keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
        input += keyInfo.KeyChar;
        if ((input.Length % 25) == 0)
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    } while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
}
```

Si quieres que además detecte el enter y empiece a contar de cero en la  nueva línea es un poco más largo, pero tampoco es complicado :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "";
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
        i++;
        input += keyInfo.KeyChar;
        if(keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            i = 0;
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        if (i == 25)
        {
            i = 0;
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    } while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
}
```

Comment: Muy bueno, es lo que quiero. Se me olvidó una cosa. Que al pulsar Enter, se guarde en una variable los textos introducidos.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiero que uses `Console.ReadKey`.

Puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
string input = "";

var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
while (input.Length < 25 && keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter){
    input += keyInfo.KeyChar;

    keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
}
```

También puedes hacer que la consola no imprima por si misma las teclas presionadas y hacer cosas como ocultar una contraseña mostrando asteriscos por cada carácter. Usando `Console.ReadKey(true)`;

Comment: No es exactamente así. Si escribo más de 25 letras, automáticamente se ponen en el siguiente renglón, es como si pulsaras Enter.

Comment: ¿No se produce el enter? ¿Cuál es el problema?